# Build .jar file with custom parameters

Tags: java, variables, build, parameters

Hello so I am trying to explain my question with an example:
Imagine I have a java project with a client's ID hardcoded in it (I know this is bad practice, typically I would use a server in the background to verify users, but just take this as a given for my question please), but I want to automatically build a jar file for every client, so is there any build command or method to build it with the client id as a parameter, maybe something like "javac Program.java -params XXXX-YYYY(clientID)"

Thanks ahead for any help with it :)

Comment: Put the properties in a properties file.  You can change for each build.

Comment: @ScaryWombat No bad idea, but the problem with that seems to be, that a client could change his own ID within the properties file and this can't definitely not be allowed :/

Comment: Having it hardcoded in your Java code isn't actually any better in that way.  It's just as easy to change.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is it though? If so, can I do it somehow programmatically and automate it. So I would just build the jar once and change it through a program.

Comment: I mean, yes, you could, but it's probably easier to do it up front.  That's a matter for your build system more than anything else.  But you will need something smarter -- probably with crypto -- to ensure the client can't change their own ID.